# Existence of natural morphism between an abelian group and a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G an abelian group, and H a subgroup of G, the question is if there are a natural morphism from G to H.

I tried to construct that morphism using the equivalence classes of G/H and choosing elements of the class, but i dont know if that election can be done in a way such that the map were a morphism.

Comment: Well, there's always the trivial homomorphism...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a finitely generated subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ (for example $\mathbb{Z}$). Then the only homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to H$ is the trivial one.

Therefore the trivial homomorphism is as much as you can get, in general.

Comment: how do you prove that in that case the only homomorphism is the trivial one?

Comment: @lecheconmilo Consider $H=\mathbb{Z}$ and $x=f(a)$, where $a$ is any element of $\mathbb{Q}$. Then, for every $n>0$ there exists $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $x=ny$: just take $y=f(a/n)$. It obviously follows that $x=0$.